# MS Word "The linked image cannot be displayed" on user's computer (creating word with HTML in Lotus Domino)

Tags: html, ms-word, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am creating MS Word with lotusscript by printing HTML. In my code I am including an image (with img tag), where src parameter is absolute path to an image saved locally on my disc. User also has the same image on the same path. But when he creates this document, instead of an image there is a message "The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location".

This is the sample of the code:

```
Print |Content-type: application/msword|
Print |Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename="fname.doc"|
Print |<HTML xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>|
Print |<HEAD>|
Print |  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'>|
Print |</HEAD>|
Print |<BODY>|
Print |  <img src="C:/myFolder/myPic.png" height="45" width="80" />|
Print |</BODY>|
Print |</HTML>|
```

I googled, but didn't find any solution so far. Any ideas?

Comment: One more thing - when they send me that doc file, I can see the pic without any problem.

Comment: One thing for the user to test is whether he's able to insert the picture into a Word document from that path - just normally into a document - in order to make sure there's no permissions problem with the folder. And then have the user try to insert the image with a link into a document, save, close and re-open the document. Just to make sure it CAN work.

Comment: Windows does some aliasing. E.g. MyDocuments is really C:\Users\UserName\Documents. And different versions of Windows may handle this differently. So is it really "C:\myFolder"? Or is something like "C:\Users\YourUserName\MyFolder"?